# Need help with simplyfying an equation.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $|a|\neq|b|$. What is the limit of $x_n = \frac{a^n-b^n}{a^n+b^n}$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in terms of simplification?

Comment: Trying to simplify $x_n$ to find its limit.

Comment: As $n$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: If I multiply by $(\frac{a-b}{a-b})$ am I right in having it simplify to 1?

Comment: Not quite, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $a  = 0$, then $x_n = -1$ and if $b = 0$, $x_n = 1$. Otherwise, we can write 
$a = kb$. In this case

$$x_n = \frac{k^n b^n - b^n}{k^n b^n + b^n} = \frac{k^n - 1}{k^n + 1}$$

which is easier to take the limit.

We can't have $k = 1, -1$ by stipulation. You should consider the case for which $|k| > 1$ and the case for which $|k| < 1$.

Comment: Clean answer, +1